# How to create a method that will take in values from an array?

Tags: java

There is more to this code (like the arrays adamsCharges and adamsPayments) but this is just a snippet of the section that I need help on.
Im supposed to create a method called runMonthlyUpdate that will:

increase the debt by the monthly charges that incurred this month.

decrease the debt by the amount paid this month.

apply the interest rate to the remaining debt.

```
 public static class CreditCard 
{

    String userName;
    int debtInCents;
    double monthlyInterestRate;

    CreditCard(String name, int initialBalance, double initialInterestRate) {
        userName = name;
        debtInCents = initialBalance;
        monthlyInterestRate = initialInterestRate;
    }
public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])
{

    debtInCents += adamsCharges[t];
    debtInCents -= adamsPayments[t];
    debtInCents += monthlyInterestRate*debtInCents;
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

/BankOf5J.java:17: error: ']' expected
    public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])

/BankOf5J.java:17: error: ')' expected
    public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])

/BankOf5J.java:17: error: illegal start of type
    public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])

/BankOf5J.java:17: error: ']' expected
    public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])

/BankOf5J.java:17: error: illegal start of type
    public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])

/BankOf5J.java:17: error:  expected
    public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])

/BankOf5J.java:17: error: ';' expected
    public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])

Comment: You should start with a basic **JAVA Tutorial** on functions and how to pass parameters.

Comment: Well, Java methods have parameter **TYPES**, so you need to put something like `int` or `String` in the method to tell the compiler what type to expect: `void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])`  Refer to the constructor directly above for an example how this looks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple errors in this code snippet

The method definition of

`public void runMonthlyUpdate( adamsCharges[t], adamsPayments[t])` is incorrect.

While declaring a method , the "type" of the arguments has to be specified. So you should specify the type of adamsCharges[t] and adamsPayments[t] which would something like int or float or double etc.

Correct code would be

```
public void runMonthlyUpdate( int charges, int payments)
{

debtInCents += charge;
debtInCents -= payments;
debtInCents += monthlyInterestRate*debtInCents;
}
```

While calling or using the function , pass adamCharges[t]  and adamPayments[t]

```
runMonthlyPayment(adamCharges[t] , adamPayments[t]);
```

To access all the values in the arrays (assuming both arrays have the same length)
do something like :

```
for (int t = 0 ; t < adamCharges.length ; t++)
{
     runMonthlyPayment(adamCharges[t] , adamPayments[t]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining function pass array as a whole and pass index as in your case int t. Try to learn how to call and define functions in java.